# TSQL - Can't seem to PIVOT output from a CTE (Invalid object name error)

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, common-table-expression

The following is output from a CTE when I do a SELECT * FROM CTE_RESULTS

> Desciption   Closing Balance 
>   A    38909554.57
>   B    -30068540.13
>   C    731413.26
>   D    182167
>   E    -53016969.08
>   F    24768896.85

I then write a pivot to change how this is displayed so I can do further queries that perform calculations on the associated value of each "Description"

For example: I want to calculate

> A*B*C/F (ficticious calculation for lets call it "Profit" for simplicity)
>   C+D*E (ficticious calculation for lets call it "Profit Ratio" for simplicity)
>   etc

And to have these results displayed in another table like:

> Calculations  RESULTS
>   Profit        65466787878 (random number representing the value of A*B*C/F)
>   Profit Ratio  345678864 (random number representing the value of C+D*E)

This is where I am going with it.

My issue now is creating the pivot. The query SELECT * FROM CTE_RESULTS works, so it isn't an issue with my CTE.

However, when I do a pivot:

> SELECT [Description], [A] AS 'A', [B] AS 'B', [C] AS 'C', [D] AS 'D', [E] AS 'E', [F] AS 'F'
>   FROM 
>     (SELECT [Description], [CLOSING BALANCE] FROM CTE_RESULTS)  AS SRC
>     PIVOT (MAX([CLOSING BALANCE]) FOR [Description] IN 'A','B','C','D','E','F')) AS PVT;

I get an error:

> Invalid object name 'CTE_RESULTS'

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems with your query, but neither would cause the error `Invalid object name 'CTE_RESULTS'`.

The first is that you are using single quotes within the CTE to reference columns names, this is only allowed for aliases. You need to use square brackets:

```
FOR [Description] IN ([A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F])
```

Secondly, you are referencing the column `[Description]` in your select list, but this is removed by the pivot (as it is becoming columns) so you will get an invalid column name error.

Your final query should be something like:

```
WITH CTE_RESULTS AS
(   SELECT  *
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  [A] AS 'A', [B] AS 'B', [C] AS 'C', [D] AS 'D', [E] AS 'E', [F] AS 'F'
FROM    (   SELECT [Description], [CLOSING BALANCE] 
            FROM    CTE_RESULTS
        )  AS SRC
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX([CLOSING BALANCE]) 
            FOR [Description] IN ([A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F])
        ) AS PVT;
```

Which gives:

```
   A     |     B     |   C    |   D    |    E      |    F
---------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------
38909554 | -30068540 | 731413 | 182167 | -53016969 | 24768896
```

**[Working Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1d8c/4)**

Comment: No worries, This is one of the reasons I tend to avoid using single quotes for anything other literals, block quotes are never ambiguous and always refer to an objects, whereas single quotes can be interpreted differently depending on their location. It is entirely subjective, but although not immediately convinced I have now adopted the `alias = ColumnName` syntax after reading [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)